# retriving active record based on a has_many and belong_to on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

In my database schema i have a model named by City, and a model named by instituitions.
so, City has_many instituitions, ans instituitions belongs_to City.

how do i retrive in cities_controller
@cities = ???
the cities who has at least one institution.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find the cities that have at least one institution associated with them you can do:

```
City.joins(:institutions).distinct
```

- In case you need to find the cities that don't have any institutions associated with them:

```
City.where.missing(:institutions)
```